# Truffles: how do I pick between buying truffle or truffle oil?

Tags: truffles

I'm interested in buying truffles in one form or another to be used as a seasoning for omelettes and pastas and such.

The main two truffle products available are fresh truffles and truffle oil. Truffle oil sometimes contains no real truffle, but some kind of synthetic aroma that imitates the truffle aroma (however, I'm interested in oils that have real truffle).

Price-wise, should I be looking at oils or buy straight fresh truffle and use it as I wish? I've heard a claim that truffle oils should be a more inexpensive way to get the truffle aroma, but upon comparing the prices of truffle oils with real truffle and fresh truffle, I'm not sure.

E.g. I can purchase truffle for £45 for 15g or 250ml of truffle oil for £12.50. Which one is affordable should depend on how much 250ml of truffle oil might have actual truffle and whether one would get more truffle by buying fresh truffle instead.

So should I look into purchasing and using truffle or truffle oil, if I want the most (real) truffle aroma per buck?

Comment: Sorry, it is up to you to decide which one you want to have. We cannot make shopping recommendations - both products have their fans. There is no way for us, of for you, to predict what you will like and what will appear "worth it" relative to your personal financial situation. The only way to be sure is to try both and compare, and decide for yourself.

Comment: I think mavavilj is trying to ascertain whether the truffle flavor concentration in truffle oil makes the price of the oil more or less economical (in terms of price per unit "truffliness") than purchasing straight truffles. I imagine the spoiling properties of the two products would also enter into his decision, along with maybe other considerations, but this seems like a pretty objective question for someone knowledgeable about this topic, and not solely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Reopening (with a tweaked title) because of pretty much what Lorel C. said here - seems like there's a fairly objective question here, it's not just about which is "better".

Comment: Agreed that the new wording is better. A hint: if you edit a closed question to improve it towards being on-topic again, please also click on "reopen", so it gets on the queue and people see it and vote on reopening.

Comment: As 'truffle oil' stores for longer ... maybe you could buy a fresh truffle, use some, and then infuse your own oil for later?

Answer (score 1):

If you want "the most (real) truffle aroma", as you write, there is no question that it will come from real truffles.  With a bit of Internet searching you can see that truffle oil is generally a chemically derived product.  While we can debate whether or not any flavor or aroma that is created in the "lab" is the same as the real thing, you specifically want to experience "real" truffle.  The only way to do that is with the authentic item.  The challenge is that truffle aroma/flavor is fleeting.  So, the closer to unearthing and the closer to the source the better.  To me, truffle is a unique and special item.  So, when you want to experience it, get the best and most real truffle you can afford.  Have fun using it in dishes that highlight its aroma and flavor, then wait for the next special occasion.